# Header hiding on scroll positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have included a snippet to show the general idea of what I have right now. The snippet will show a header and if you scroll the header stays the same size until the full height of the header has been scrolled down and then it will go away. Then when you scroll up (when the header gone) the header will show.

The issue I cannot seem to figure out is how to remove the `position: fixed` from my css and still get the javascript to work. I want the header to scroll down normally (just like Stack overflow's header), however with the ability to still re-appear when scrolling up.

I tried taking out `position: fixed` and the script broke. I also tried adding `position: fixed` to the `nav-up` class...neither change worked.

Does anyone know what I could do to make this work?

```js
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event){
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if (didScroll) {
        hasScrolled();
        didScroll = false;
    }
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    
    // Make sure they scroll more than delta
    if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
        return;
    
    // If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
    // This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
    if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
        // Scroll Down
        $('header').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
    } else {
        // Scroll Up
        if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
            $('header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
        }
    }
    
    lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

```css
html, body {
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
}
header {
    /*background: #2F4F4F;*/
 /*background: #53868B;*/
 /*background: #35586C;*/
 background: #F2F2F2;
    height: 120px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
    width: 100%;
 z-index: 100;
}

.nav-up {
    top: -120px;
}
#logo {
 padding: 5px 20%;
 display: inline-block;
}
#logo img {
 height: 110px;
 width: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="nav-down">
 <div id="logo">
  <img src="images/eslich.png" alt="">
 </div>
</header>
<br><br><Br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><Br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><Br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><Br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

This is the new jsfiddle using her code https://jsfiddle.net/jz8aa5yz/2/

```
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event){
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if (didScroll) {
        hasScrolled();
        didScroll = false;
    }
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    // Make sure they scroll more than delta
    if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
        return;

    // If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
    // This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
    if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
        // Scroll Down
        $('header').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
    } else {
            if (st < navbarHeight) {
            if (st === 0 || st < 50) {
            $('header').css('position', 'static');
          }
        } else {
            $('header').css('position', 'fixed');
        }
        // Scroll Up
        if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
            $('header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
        }
    }

    lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

`

### Old

I'm still testing some javascript, but I wonder if the effect you wanted is something like this? I did a few things different, but the main things were using `hide()`, `css()`, `slideUp()`, `slideDown()`, and `if / else` statements. Here's a [jsfiddle of the example](https://jsfiddle.net/zdcr51df/)

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var header = $("header");
            var lastScrollTop = 0;

            $(window).on("scroll", function () {
                currentScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

                if ($("body").scrollTop() > header.outerHeight()) {
                    if (currentScrollTop > lastScrollTop) {
                        if (header.css("position") == "fixed") {
                            header.slideUp();
                        } else {
                            header.css({
                                display: "none",
                                position: "fixed"
                            });
                        }
                    } else {
                        header.slideDown();
                    }
                } else {
                    if (currentScrollTop === 0) {
                        header.css({
                            display: "block",
                            position: "static"
                        });
                    }
                }

                lastScrollTop = currentScrollTop;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Yes, that is pretty much what I am looking for, just if the header stays at the top when scrolling back up...even close to the top of the page. Yours goes away and then comes back really quickly.

Comment: Lol, I overlooked that. I'll fix it really quick

Comment: Alright, change was made in top most else statement to see if scroll reached the top before resetting.

Comment: I can't tell the difference? The way mine slides up is exacly how I like it. It seems "choppy" any other way. Is there anyway to make it like I have it now - going up, but yours how it goes down?

Comment: Please refer to the new jsfiddle. It seems to work, I've only tested in edge, chrome, and firefox so far. Where it says `|| st < 50` feel free to remove that.

Comment: What does `|| st < 50` do? This works pretty much spot on! I appreciate the help!!

Comment: You're welcome. It was doing some weird hitch sometimes when scrolling up and the header got close to the top, so I added that to try and prevent it. Feel free to adjust it and see what it does